# “that for which” -grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I was just swiping through Instagram stories the other day and saw that someone posted a photo of a presentation in which the following sentence was written:

> Do not say that for which you lack adequate evidence.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? I understand the meaning of it, and how it’s structured; the sentence just somehow doesn’t feel right.

Comment: It's rather formal. More natural would be "Do not say what you lack adequate evidence for", or "Do not say that which you lack adequate evidence for".

Comment: It's also a way of obeying the obsolete / dubious / mistaken  rule "Never end a sentence with a preposition". You will note that both of Bill's alternatives end in "for". But as he also says it's perfectly good, grammatical English.

Comment: @PeterJennings That's literally only a followed rule of English in Jamaica. Funny story. If you want to hear it, reply and I'll move this to chat.

Comment: @gotube I looked up that "rule" here on ELL and over on EL&U and the answers all came down to "It's a made up rule that has no basis in standard English grammar". Apparently it's a hangover from Latin grammar (where it really is a rule) adopted by some 18th century grammar books but having no validity in English. Google it and read the first hit you get. By all means move this to a chat, I'd like to hear any funny stories.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136001/discussion-on-question-by-tk-kim-that-for-which-grammatically-correct).

Comment: @PeterJennings Done